# A problem with layouts language

Tags: zwpagelayout

First I'd like to give a minimal working sample:

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\printinunitsof{cm}
\oddpagelayoutfalse
%\currentpage
%\drawmarginparsfalse %marginnote
\printheadingsfalse
\pagediagram
\pagevalues
\caption{页面结构图} \label{fig:pplt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiling it with **XeLatex**, I get the following PDF file

[image]

My **QUESTIONS** are

1. How to replace the texts of "Header, Body, Footer and Margin Note"
   with "页眉，主体，页脚 and 边注” respectively？
2. How to replace the texts (The circle ...) at the head of the page with its Chinese translations?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `patchcmd` to replace the hard-coded English text in the `layout.sty` package, like in the following code:

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{layouts}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\drawpage}
 {\begin{small} The circle is at 1 inch from the top and left of the
  page. Dashed lines represent (\texttt{\bs hoffset + 1 inch}) and
  (\texttt{\bs voffset + 1 inch}) from the top and left of the
  page.}
 {\begin{small} 中文……}
 {}
 {}

\patchcmd{\drawpage}
 {{\l@ylabelfont Header}}
 {{\l@ylabelfont 页眉}}
 {}
 {}

\patchcmd{\drawpage}
 {{\l@ylabelfont Body}}
 {{\l@ylabelfont 主体}}
 {}
 {}

\patchcmd{\drawpage}
 {{\l@ylabelfont Footer}}
 {{\l@ylabelfont 页脚}}
 {}
 {}

\patchcmd{\drawpage}
 {{\l@ylabelfont\shortstack{Margin\\Note}}}
 {{\l@ylabelfont 边注}}
 {}
 {}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\printinunitsof{cm}
\oddpagelayoutfalse
%\currentpage
%\drawmarginparsfalse %marginnote
\printheadingsfalse
\pagediagram
\pagevalues
\caption{页面结构图} \label{fig:pplt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You should enter a proper translation for “The circle …”.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I have not your language in my system, so I answer with the  corresponding Greek words in the place of your requested.

The whole idea is to  place the original image inside a tikzpicture, and then to place another tikzpicture over the original and to write over the words our replacements in a white font (to cover old words):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0){\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\printinunitsof{cm}%
\oddpagelayoutfalse%
%\currentpage
%\drawmarginparsfalse %marginnote
\printheadingsfalse%
\drawpage%
%\pagediagram
\pagevalues%
\captionof{figure}{Left-hand two-column page layout parameters} \label{fig:pplt}%
\end{minipage}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[text width=2cm,fill=white] at ([yshift=1.9cm,xshift=0.4cm]current page.center){Σώμα};
  \node[text width=2cm,fill=white,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at ([yshift=-2.74cm,xshift=0.4cm]current page.center){Υποσέλιδο};
  \node[text width=2cm,fill=white,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at ([yshift=6.4cm,xshift=0.4cm]current page.center){Κεφαλίδα};
  \node[text width=1cm,fill=white,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at ([yshift=1.4cm,xshift=-4.57cm]current page.center){Περι- θώριο};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a bit complicated and so it can't be changed with the different pages! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is just a hack I use to manipulate images (keep it in mind for such jobs but wait for a better answer in case that some of the commands have an automated translation or a way to be translated). I just added the answer as a last option in case you can't do it other way and also as a general idea on similar tasks

Comment: With the documentclass `ctexbook` you can use these Chinese characters and compile it with XeLatex.

Comment: I don't have this document class available in my system... and also, the systems (at least linux) needs the language installed to show these characters. I tried to copy paste them instead my greek... but it doesn't work... I have to add the support of the language... I think you can try it and see if it works... I can not.